# Make or disable mysql auto upgrade during the booting stage

Tags: mysql

I find that mysql always try to auto-upgrade in the booting stage:

```
sudo journalctl -b -l | grep  mysql
Feb 04 13:05:35 mydebian mysqld[713]: 2021-02-04 13:05:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 713 ...
Feb 04 13:05:35 mydebian mysqld[713]: 2021-02-04 13:05:35 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32184)
Feb 04 13:05:41 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[822]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[826]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Feb 04 13:05:42 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[837]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
```

I display all action mysql try to take during os booting stage everytime,mysql try to upgrade but  failed .It is my turn to solve the issue,which is the best--make or disable mysql auto upgrade  in the booting stage?How to help mysql auto-upgrade then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best approach is to leave the `root` user for packaging with `unix_socket` authentication so it can be secure be able to do updates.

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket
```

If you need root you can run `mysql` as the unix root user and be authenticated. For day-to-day admin, create your own user.

```
CREATE USER showkey@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket
```

ref: [Authentication unix socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/)

Or with a password:

```
CREATE USER showkey@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD('pwd')
```

And then give that user grants:

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* TO showkey@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: A character  `T` lost in  `CREATE USER showkey@localhost IDENIFIED VIA unix_socket`.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried the two methods in my pc.
It is no use to create a new user.

```
CREATE USER showkey@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO showkey@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Issue remains ,booting log is the same as before,maybe the reason is that auto upgrade script executed with root at the booting,it is no related with new created user `showkey`.
It is the proper way to make the mysql as the unix root user and be authenticated with

```
CREATE USER showkey@localhost IDENIFIED VIA unix_socket
```

Reboot my pc then check the booting log.

```
sudo journalctl -b |grep   mysql
Feb 04 17:54:39 mydebian mysqld[690]: 2021-02-04 17:54:39 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 690 ...
Feb 04 17:54:39 mydebian mysqld[690]: 2021-02-04 17:54:39 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 16384 (request: 32184)
Feb 04 17:54:44 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[792]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[796]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[796]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[796]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[796]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 10.3.27-MariaDB, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[805]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Feb 04 17:54:46 mydebian /etc/mysql/debian-start[809]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables and aria-recover for all Aria tables
```